# Wordpress posts missing unless using default URL structure

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, fishpig

I've got a Wordpress install running alongside Magento and they were previously integrated using the Fishpig extension. I've recently turned off Fishpig integration because I want to use a new theme for Wordpress.

The theme has installed fine but posts and categories appear as missing if the URL in Wordpress is set to display as anything other than the default. eg. /?cat=2 rather than /category/other.

Has anyone experienced this before and know a solution?

Comment: What are your permalink settings?

Comment: Check http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks for the right settings

Comment: I've tried changing the permalink to all possible settings, but only Default will work. It needs to be "Day and name"

Comment: make sure you have apache module mod_rewrite enabled.

Comment: mod_rewrite is already enabled. Still no luck